# First position of true value(1) from a bit pattern

Tags: php, bit-manipulation

For example, if the pattern is as follows:

```
bit        [10010][1011][1000]
position    54321  4321  4321  
result         2      1  4
```

I want to get the result from right to left position as `[2] [1] [4]`

Comment: What language?  Is your pattern a string?  Show sample code and what you've tried so far.

Comment: i want to use bit to store something like this: array('php' => 36 /* '0100100' */ ) . 'php' is search key and '0100100' means which article have the php keyworld. how can i get the first position(3) of true value 1 form '0100100'.

Comment: thanks everyone, now i use code "$n = log($x & (~$x+1))/log(2)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you are looking for a function that returns the index of the least significant 1-bit in an integer. If so, check whether your platform implements the function `ffs()` ("find first set"). On Linux, you can do `man ffs` to get the full documentation. On other programming platforms the function may be named differently, e.g. in NVIDIA's CUDA, it exists as a device function `__ffs()`.

Comment: thx, i find code [ffs.c](http://cristi.indefero.net/p/uClibc-cristi/source/tree/b32dd708df63d90f9d755b6c0de2588200e432ca/libc/string/ffs.c), and conv to php. that's great.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the bit pattern is represented by an int you could do something like

```
if(bitPattern == 0) {
    return 0;
}

int count = 1;
while(bitPattern % 2 == 0) {
    bitPattern >>= 1;
    count++;
}
return count;
```

Comment: +1 with the caveat that `bitPattern = 0` will result in an infinite loop.  You'd need to check for a `0` value first.

Comment: if bit pattern is "1000000000000000000000000000000", it will do 31 times loop.

Comment: @nroe: there may be a better way to do it, but yes that's the worst case.

Comment: @nroe:  and a loop with just a shift and an increment is pretty tight.  The condition could even be `while(bitPattern & 1 == 0)` which would be better.

Comment: @Andrew Cooper: i known it will very fast. but if a have 1 Million bit. it will do to much loop when they have a lot of false vaule(0)

Comment: @nroe: this may be a case of just testing it out and if you determine it's too slow for your purposes then optimize from there.  If it's too slow and there isn't a faster way to do this then maybe the overlying algorithm could be tweaked to allow you to get this value in constant time.

Answer (score 0):

```php
$n = log($x & (~$x+1))/log(2)
```

~x + 1 is exact the same as -x, as the result of the 2's complement. So why would you use the more complex and slower?

And there are many bithacks to quickly find integer log<sub>2</sub>x instead of using the much more slower floating point log as above. No slowly divide is needed too. Since x & -x yields only the last bit which is a power of 2, you can use the following function to get log<sub>2</sub>

```c
unsigned int log2p2(unsigned int v)  // 32-bit value to find the log2 of v
{
    static const unsigned int b[] = {0xAAAAAAAA, 0xCCCCCCCC, 0xF0F0F0F0, 
                                     0xFF00FF00, 0xFFFF0000};
    register unsigned int r = (v & b[0]) != 0;
    for (i = 4; i > 0; i--) // unroll for speed...
    {
        r |= ((v & b[i]) != 0) << i;
    }
}
```

There are many other ways to calculate log<sub>2</sub>x which you can find [here](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerLogObvious)

So your code is now simply

```c
log2p2(x & -x);
```